# Override DefaultInvoice.php file to render custom row in magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4.4, override-model, invoice-pdf

I need to override Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice.php file to render a custom row in Magento 2.4.4

I tried with preferences like

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice"/>
```

it gives the following error while print the invoice pdf

```
Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource in /app/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
```

This is related to gift wrap and I want to render item wise wrap items data like wrap image, wrap name, etc. like the below

If there are 2 items in order then 2 wrap data is available, so I need to show 2 raw but when I add

```
$this->_drawItemWrap($item, $page, $order);
```

line in getPdf function it throw error

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice\Interceptor::drawWrap
```

I rendered that function like below

```
protected function _drawItemWrap(
  \Magento\Framework\DataObject $item,
  \Zend_Pdf_Page $page,
  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
) {
  $type = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductType();
  $renderer = $this->_getRenderer($type);
  $renderer->setOrder($order);
  $renderer->setItem($item);
  $renderer->setPdf($this);
  $renderer->setPage($page);
  $renderer->setRenderedModel($this);
  $renderer->drawWrap();

  return $renderer->getPage();
}
```

I need to show wrap history like below image.

[image]

If anyone has the solution to rendering the custom row the same as the order item row then please suggest it.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change Invoice Item renderer for PDF the better way is overwrite it with `pdf.xml`

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/pdf.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/pdf_file.xsd">
    <renderers>
        <page type="invoice">
            <renderer product_type="default">Acme\StackExchange\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice</renderer>
        </page>
    </renderers>
</config>
```

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice.php`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\AbstractItems;

class DefaultInvoice extends AbstractItems
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function draw()
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I need to create another public function same as draw().
I created the public function drawWrap() and it gives an error 
Invalid method Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice\Interceptor::drawWrap [] []

What can I do about this?.

Comment: Please provide full code of your renderer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for the late reply from my end. I edited my question, please check once and give me a better solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MonarkBhawani You've provided another one fragment and I still cannot see full picture of issue for any advise

Comment: I want to show wrap items data same as product data in pdf.
can you render public function drawWrap() && public function draw() in Invoice/DefaultInvoice.php with same time?. Make sure these 2 functions are working and render the data.

Comment: @VictorThonchuk Any clue?.